# Making sense of sample space, sigma fields and probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Just trying to get my head around writing out the technical definitions of sample space and events in terms of sets, given a situation.

Consider the following example.

There are two urns. Urn 1 contains 2 white and 3 blue balls. Urn 2 contains 3 white and 4 blue balls. A ball is drawn randomly from Urn 1 and placed into Urn 2. Then a ball is picked at random from Urn 2 and examined. We are interested in the probability of this ball being blue.

Let $B$ be the event the ball taken from Urn 1 is blue.

I am trying to write out what $\Omega$, $\mathcal{F}$ and $B$ would be in terms of sets.

My guess is that

$$
\begin{align*}
\Omega&=\{(b,b),(b,w),(w,b),(w,w)\}\\
\mathcal{F}&=\{0,1\}^\Omega\\
B&=\{(b,b),(b,w)\}
\end{align*}
$$

Are these the most natural definitions?

Comment: I think that there are two answers to your question and both are correct and interesting in their own right. The first answer is from a modelling/philosophical point of view: what is randomness? This is an extremely abstract concept. Consequently, mathematicians often prefer to use an \emph{abstract} sampling space $\Omega$ that isn't specified at all. Instead, they focus on the random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow E$ that transports the randomness into the experiment we are performing. In this sense, there are infinitely many correct choices of (abstract) sampling spaces. [I had to split it]

Comment: The second answer, to which you are probably (no pun intended) referring is to take the concrete sampling space of the experiment. Again, multiple choices are possible. If you really are only interested in the sampling of the ball from the first urn, you might even choose $\Omega = \{ w,b\}$ and $B=\{b\}$. However, if you are, in general, interested in both balls, your sampling space is the correct one and your set is, too. Your concept of $\sigma$-algebra, however, isn't. A $\sigma$-algebra is a set of subsets of $\Omega$. In the finite setting, one usually chooses $\mathcal{F} = 2^\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you. I think that is just notation. The text I’m working from uses $\{0,1/}^\Omega$ to indicate the power set of the sample space

Comment: True! I misread that.